# How to call JavaScript function with params from ASP.NET Core 8 with JSImport interop?

Tags: javascript, interop, webassembly, .net-8.0

Using a wasmbrowser project and ASP.NET Core 8 I can call .NET from Javascript with JSImport interop

Microsoft documentation includes this example without any params.

C#

```
[JSImport("window.location.href", "main.js")]
internal static partial string GetHRef();
```

JavaScript

```
setModuleImports("main.js", {
  window: { 
    location: {
      href: () => globalThis.window.location.href
    }
  }
});`
```

How can I do the same if I have parameters? For example how can I write setModuleImports if I have this function on C# side

```
[JSImport("window.location.test", "main.js")]
internal static partial string Test(string a, int b);
```

I am trying this in a wasmbrowser NET8 project. In documentation [JavaScript interop on WASM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/dotnet-interop?view=aspnetcore-8.0#javascript-interop-on-) it looks possible but I haven't found a way yet

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and you should just do it like this

C#

```
[JSImport("ping4", "main.js")]
internal static partial string Ping4(string a, int b);
```

js

```
setModuleImports("main.js", {
    ping4: (a, b) =>  { return a + ";" + b; }
  });
```

usage

```
Ping4("hi", 7) returns "hi;7"
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I don't know how you found this, since things are so poorly documented. You saved my life though.